# Как сделать сегментированный progress bar на android?

Tags: android, material-design, progress-bar

Есть два повторяющихся действия. Хочу отобразить их прогресс. Количество повторений конечно, время неизменно.

Как сделать такой *Progress bar*? Т.е. разделенный на сегменты:

```
красный - `действие1`, синий - `действие2`, серый - `background`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE: Появилась идея склеить несколько прогресс баров в LinearLayout. Добавлять их динамически через код, сколько потребуется. Выглядит прям как надо. Насколько это корректное решение?